# Installing Avahi on FreeBSD - Daemon Doesn't Start

Tags: software-installation, package-management, freebsd, avahi

I've just installed package avahi-app-0.6.31_5 on a fairly-clean FreeBSD 10.3, but the service isn't starting on its own. I've consulted the documentation and discovered that there isn't any.

Can anyone fill me in on what I've overlooked?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In FreeBSD, you have to [explicitly allow](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/configtuning-starting-services.html) services outside the core system to start. In your `/etc/rc.conf` add the following line:

```
avahi_daemon_enable="YES"
```

(You might also need `avahi_dnsconfd_enable="YES"`.)

Comment: That would be exactly what I overlooked. I think I've been away from BSD too long.